# why recurring to run npm version patch ; npm publish?

Tags: node.js, npm

With `npm version patch`, I can easily promote the npm package version.

Then I add below line in `package.json`

```
"publish": "npm version patch; npm publish"
```

When I run `npm run publish`, I suppose to get the version pumped and publish automatically.

But it is not. The command goes crazy to pump and publish new version again and again.

```
$ npm run publish

> npm-test-package@2.0.3 publish ....

> npm version patch; npm publish

v2.0.4

> npm-test-package@2.0.4 publish .
> npm version patch; npm publish

v2.0.5

> npm-test-package@2.0.5 publish .
> npm version patch; npm publish

v2.0.6

> npm-test-package@2.0.6 publish .
> npm version patch; npm publish

v2.0.7
^C
```

Why it works crazy? Any hints for me?

Comment: I've provided an answer, but it's worth noting that you might not always want to create a new patch version. You do know about semver right?

Comment: Thanks, I knew semver. My question is, why it is lost of control, what's the root cause to make the infinite loop?

Comment: I'll let you think more about that.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it works after I change to

```
"push": "npm version patch; npm publish"
```

So the key word `publish` can't be used with `npm run` command

Comment: Even if renaming prevents solves the issue is not the correct answer. Using "prepublishOnly" hook is the right way to do it.

Comment: never mind, my solution would be less typing. There is no wrong to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is creating an infinite loop and you have figured that out by yourself.

What you can do is to create a `prepublishOnly` script. For example:

```
{
  "prepublishOnly": "npm version patch"
}
```